# Markdown and DITA OT: Variables in square brackets are not resolved in PDF

Tags: markdown, dita-ot

I am building a new Docker image using ghcr.io/dita-ot/dita-ot:3.6.1 as a base and adding some custom PDF and HTML DITA OT plugins.

In addition to DITA format, I also build Markdown.
I add keyrefs to the ditamap and then reference them as [name] in the Markdown source file. They are perfectly resolved in HTML5 output by showing the respective keyref value.

The are not, however, resolved in PDF. The interesting thing is that when I build from oXygen using the same custom PDF plugin - everything is resolved, even the code blocks are highlighted, which obviosly does not happen when building the same document using the custom Docker image.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue with variables and codeblocks?

Comment: Maybe not to mix it up, I want to understand what is missing from the custom PDF plugin in my case, or if it even need to support such processing. I found a template in HTML5 that potentially does this transformation, but is  it possible to replicate it for PDF?

Comment: <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/keyword ')]" name="topic.keyword">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@keyref and @href">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="turning-to-link">
          <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'keyword'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <span class="keyword">
          <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
          <xsl:call-template name="setidaname"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>  
        </span>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>